# Pig `Failed to create DataStorage` to Hadoop cluster in Docker ENV

Tags: hadoop, docker, apache-pig

I'm trying to run Pig and Hadoop in my local machine (OSX) to test the script but I can't seem to connect Hadoop in Docker.

I have Pig setup locally. I installed Hadoop from https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/ and I run the machine with this command

```
docker run -it sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.7.0 -p 50010:50010 -p 19888:19888 /etc/bootstrap.sh -bash
```

I can boot Hadoop docker.

I looked at `Dockerfile` to see which ports are exposed. https://github.com/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile#L103

Here's my `hadoop-site.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://192.168.99.100:50010</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>hdfs://192.168.99.100:19888</value>
</property>
<property> 
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>8</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx512m</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

And when I run `Pig` I get this error.

```
e.xml to override properties of core-default.xml, mapred-default.xml and hdfs-default.xml respectively
15/12/28 12:29:04 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
15/12/28 12:29:04 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE
15/12/28 12:29:04 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType
2015-12-28 12:29:04,982 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.15.0 (r1682971) compiled Jun 01 2015, 11:43:55
2015-12-28 12:29:04,982 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /Users/ncharass/opensource/pig-0.15.0/conf/pig_1451323744980.log
2015-12-28 12:29:04,995 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /Users/ncharass/.pigbootup not found
2015-12-28 12:29:05,141 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://192.168.99.100:50010
2015-12-28 12:29:05,371 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Failed to create DataStorage
Details at logfile: /Users/ncharass/opensource/pig-0.15.0/conf/pig_1451323744980.log
2015-12-28 12:29:05,383 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Pig script completed in 468 milliseconds (468 ms)
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Docker runs in a Virtual machine on OSX (and Windows).

Exposing docker ports is different than forwarding ports in VirtualBox.

Have you forwarded the appropriate ports in VirtualBox under Settings > Network > Advanced > Port Forwarding?

Comment: It seems like Pig can connect to Hadoop. But it failed here `ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Failed to create DataStorage`

Comment: It might fail to create datastorage if it can't connect to HDFS. The line before that says it's trying to connect. If you SSH to the docker box and run pig, I bet it'll work

Comment: Thanks I'll try now.

Comment: I did that still doesn't work. It failed with the same message

Comment: Are the YARN and HDFS services running?